# How to display data changes in DynamoDB data live in a Vue app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Vue app which is displaying data from DynamoDB. But the data in the DDB table is updated frequently and as a result the end user needs to see the updated data as well.

What is the best approach to display live changes of the data ?
I'm not using a GraphQL API so using GraphQL subscriptions is not feasable for me here.

I was thinking of using a cronjob but wasn't sure whether that would be ideal.

Comment: The data which is continously being updated and is essential for user to see, you can call your API after every 5 seconds or create a refresh button at top of the page

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AWS SDK on client with temporary credential to make AWS request, you can implement lambda event trigger with sqs long poll. So it will has several steps :

1. Enable dynamodb stream
2. Create a lambda function and mapping the dynamodb as event source

Now you have a function running behind dynamodb. So anything dynamodb request from client will be triggering event to lambda that contains the requested ddb info

Once you succeed with that, the next step is setting up the permission to have sqs access

3. Create a sqs queue
4. Add new policy to lambda role to have access sqs:SendMessage to sqs resources created
5. Add new policy to your IAM authenticated/unauthenticated role to have access sqs:ReceiveMessage, sqs:DeleteMessage

Well, until here you have already to update the both lambda and client code. The pseudocode of lambda function :

- getting dynamodb events
- SendMessage to sqs queue

The pseudocode of client:

- request AWS temp credential
- make sqs long poll by ReceiveMessage method
- once got new message, requery the DSB and call SQS DeleteMessage method to prevent duplicate polling

The simple flow will be previewed like so

```
Client -> AWS SDK -> dynamodb -> lambda -> AWS sdk -> sqs (clients write to dynamodb)
Client -> AWS SDK -> sqs (clients make long poll)
Client -> AWS SDK -> dynamodb (clients read to dynamodb)
```

Links:

[Process New Items with DynamoDB Streams and Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.Tutorial.html)

[Enabling Long Polling in Amazon SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/sqs-examples-enable-long-polling.html)

Comment: I don't understand why this answer getting -1. Have you tried my approach if you like? Or just leave it if you don't like. I am implementing this approach on my projects for realtime DB with dynamodb

Comment: I have not tried your approach since I am not familiar with SQS, and also it seems a bit of an overkill. it was also not me who downvoted your answer, if that matters.

Comment: SQS long poll is cheapest one of approaches for this use case. You can use kinesis instead, but it's expensive. You can run crontab or interval request, but it will be managed on your side instead of AWS. About downvoted it doesn't matter. Just wondering why no info attached from the guy who did it, so we have knowledge of the pros or cons